# mat-slide-toggle button is locked when it is enabled

Tags: html, typescript

I want to disable mat-slide-toggle when mat-select-option on automatic at first. It`s fine but when mat-slide-toggle is enable its lock an can`t check or uncheck the button.
Here my code:

```html
 <!-- Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="timing">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> زمانبندی </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="dir-ltr">
                        <mat-select (selectionChange)="timingSelectionChange($event)" matTooltip="تعیین نوع زمانبندی" [value]="element.state_timing.value">
                            <mat-option value="automatic">خودکار</mat-option>
                            <mat-option value="manual">دستی</mat-option>
                            <mat-option value="periodic">دوره ای</mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
            </ng-container>

            <!-- Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="control">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> کنترل دستی </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                    <mat-slide-toggle #manstate_toggle color="primary" (change)="onSliderClick($event, element)" matTooltip="وضعیت تنظیم شده توسط کاربر" [disabled]="!(element.state_timing.value==='manual')">
                    </mat-slide-toggle>
                </td>
            </ng-container>
```